# Minifig head hollow stud vs blocked open & others

Tags: part-identification

These three heads have the same print. I have one I’m trying to identify. It appears to be [3626bpb0704](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0704).

[image]

However it could be [3626cpb0704](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0704):

[image]

or [3626cpb0647](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb0647):

[image]

Is there a way to determine for sure? I’m asking for advice on this part but all similar parts in general too.

Comment: When you say, "I have one", do you mean you have it, or you have a picture of it? I assume that if you have it, you could just look?

Comment: One of the mentioned minifigure heads have different print. Could you clarify what kind of information you are looking for? Do you need to identify which head (out of all mentioned) you actually own?

Answer (score 3):

The first two differ in their **mold type** (and specifically their stud type). The mold is identified by the first part of the bricklink id ("3626b" and "3626c" in your examples)

Here's an [overview of the different minifig head stud types](https://img.bricklink.com/ItemImage/EXTN/34407.png), an how they're named on bricklink :
[image]

The third has a different (but similar) **print** : most notably, differently shaped eyebrows, a wrinkle between the eyes, and a slight smirk. The print is identified by the last part of the bricklink id ("pb0704" and "pb0647" in your examples).